# java for loop 1st char of 1st string then last char of second string

Tags: java

when i input two strings of equal length, my code works just fine, but when i do it like different length of strings, it says StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

here is my code... i need to output a5b4c3d21
this is not homework, i am just studying String manipulation through for loop.
thank you in advanced.

```
String name1 = "abcd";
String name2 = "12345";
String temp = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= name1.length() || i <= name2.length(); i++) {

    temp = temp + name1.charAt(i-1) + name2.charAt(name2.length()-i);
}

System.out.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do bounds checking:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= name1.length() || i <= name2.length(); i++) {
    if (i <= name1.length()) {
        temp += name1.charAt(i - 1);
    }
    if (i <= name2.length()) {
        temp += name2.charAt(name2.length() - i);
    }
}
```

You could use the conditional operator to make it a bit less verbose:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= name1.length() || i <= name2.length(); i++) {
    temp += (i <= name1.length() ? name1.charAt(i - 1) : "") +
            (i <= name2.length() ? name2.charAt(name2.length() - i) : "");
}
```

but I recommend the first version, which is clearer.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i been thinking of the solution like 1 week and didnt come up with the right logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error here:

```
i <= name1.length() || i <= name2.length()
```

You're going up to the end of the longer string. You keep going if *either* string still has letters, so you stop when *both* strings are finished. But if the strings are different lengths, you keep going even after one string is passed.

Try:

```
i <= name1.length() && i <= name2.length()
```

Comment: That's not a logic error. OP wants the loop to keep going if either still has letters (see the desired output).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Math.max(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) to get the larger `String` length. And iterate from 0 to the length of the larger `String`. Test if each position is less then the last character of the  `String name1` if so print that character. Then test `name2`. Like

```
String name1 = "abcd";
String name2 = "12345";
for (int i = 0, len = Math.max(name1.length(), name2.length()); i < len; i++) {
    if (i < name1.length()) {
        System.out.print(name1.charAt(i));
    }
    if (i < name2.length()) {
        System.out.print(name2.charAt(name2.length() - i - 1));
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Output is (as requested)

```
a5b4c3d21
```

We might simplify the math in the second `if` by using a `StringBuilder` and `reverse()` like

```
String name1 = "abcd";
String name2 = "12345";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name2);
sb.reverse();
for (int i = 0, len = Math.max(name1.length(), sb.length()); i < len; i++) {
    if (i < name1.length()) {
        System.out.print(name1.charAt(i));
    }
    if (i < sb.length()) {
        System.out.print(sb.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

And the output is the same.

Comment: thank you but i am avoiding StringBuilder and any other objects. because i am using java and javascript to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

#### Code

```
    String name1 = "abcd";
    String name2 = "12345";
    String temp = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < name1.length() && i < name2.length(); i++) {

        temp = temp + name1.charAt(i) + name2.charAt(name2.length()-i-1);
    }
    for (; i < name1.length(); i++) {

        temp = temp + name1.charAt(i);
    }
    for (; i < name2.length(); i++) {

        temp = temp + name2.charAt(name2.length()-i-1);
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
```

#### Output

```
a5b4c3d21
```

2 loops after the first loop is to continue when one of the Strings  have greater length. First loop terminates when one of the String's end is reached